# Awk Script to process data from a trace file

Tags: awk, rows, trace, tabular

I have a table (.tr file) with different rows (events).

```
**Event**     **Time**   **PacketLength**  PacketId
sent             1              100           1
dropped          2              100           1
sent             3              100           2
sent             4.5            100           3
dropped          5              100           2
sent             6              100           4
sent             7              100           5
sent             8              100           6
sent             10             100           7
```

And I would like to create a new table as the following and I don't know how to it in AWK.

```
**SentTime**       **PacketLength        Dropped**
1                         100              Yes
3                         100              Yes     
4.5                       100
6                         100
7                         100
8                         100
10                        100
```

I have a simple code to find dropped or sent packets, time and id but I do not know how to create a column in my table with the results for dropped packets.

```
BEGIN{}
{
    Event = $1;
    Time = $2;
    Packet = $6;
    Node = $10;
    id = $11;
        if (Event=="s" && Node=="1.0.1.2"){
                printf ("%f\t %d\n", $2, $6);
        }
} 
    END {}
```

Comment: Please explain, how to achieve this as well

Comment: If a packet is dropped with id "x" and it is also sent, in the table "Time/PacketLenght(Sent)/Dropped" I would like to mark this packet as dropped.

Comment: Do not add information in comments. Just [edit] your original post showing relevant things. Also, the code you are posting is quite different from the input you are showing : O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save all the information in an array to postprocess it at the end of the file. Obviously, if the file is huge, this could cause memory problems.

```
    BEGIN  {
            template="#sentTime\t#packetLength\t#dropped";
            }
            {
            print $0; 
            event = $1; 
            time = $2; 
            packet_length = $3;
            packet_id = $4; 
            # save all the info in an array
            packet_info[packet_id] = packet_info[packet_id] "#" packet_length "#" time "#" event;
            }
    END     {
            # traverse the information of the array 
            for( time in packet_info ) 
            {
                print "the time is: " time " = " packet_info[time];
                # for every element in the array (= packet), 
                # the data has this format "#100#1#sent#100#2#dropped"
                split( packet_info[time], info, "#" );
                # info[2] <-- 100
                # info[3] <-- 1
                # info[4] <-- sent
                # info[5] <-- 100
                # info[6] <-- 2
                # info[7] <-- dropped
                line = template; 
                line = gensub( "#sentTime", info[3], "g", line );
                line = gensub( "#packetLength", info[2], "g", line ); 
                if( info[4] == "dropped" ) 
                    line = gensub( "#dropped", "yes", "g", line );
                if( info[7] == "dropped" ) 
                    line = gensub( "#dropped", "yes", "g", line );
                line = gensub( "#dropped", "", "g", line );
                print line; 
            } # for 
            }
```

Comment: this is an humongous piece of code with many unnecessary parts and very weird output. I don't understand why it got accepted.

Comment: @fedorqui I humbly think that my solution is more easy to understand. and to change the format of the output, or the behaviour. Bear in mind that I think that the person who posted the problem need to change the program afterwards.

Comment: The power of a language is to design *in* that language. You are programming in another language *using* `awk`. There are many reiterative blocks. Not to mention that the output is not the one the OP asked for, that many things can be just omitted, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would say...

```
awk '/sent/{pack[$4]=$2; len[$4]=$3}
     /dropped/{drop[$4]}
     END {print "Sent time", "PacketLength", "Dropped";
         for (p in pack) 
               print pack[p], len[p], ((p in drop)?"yes":"")
     }' file
```

This stores the packages in `pack[]`, the lengths in `len[]` and the dropped in `drop[]`, so that they are fetched later on.

#### Test

```
$ awk '/sent/{pack[$4]=$2; len[$4]=$3} /dropped/{drop[$4]} END {print "Sent time", "PacketLength", "Dropped"; for (p in pack) print pack[p], len[p], ((p in drop)?"yes":"")}' a
Sent time PacketLength Dropped
1 100 yes
3 100 yes
4.5 100 
6 100 
7 100 
8 100 
10 100
```

Comment: My trace file has 100000 lines and I run the awk script with the following command  awk -f results.awk out.tr > results.txt How can I run it?

Comment: Just get the code I provided and run it directly in the command line like I described in the `Test` part. `awk '...' out.tr > results.txt` should make it.